# Нужны ли кавычки в этих случаях?

Tags: кавычки

Традиция и модернизация в «народной культуре» современного Туниса: итоги и перспективы.
Сложение традиции: «народная культура» доколониального Туниса.
В ходе своего первого посещения страны у автора возникло  предположение о более сложном характере «народной культуры» современного Туниса,...
Понятия «город» и «деревня» часто противопоставляются друг другу в «народной культуре».
Усвоенные в молодые годы основы «народной культуры» определяют менталитет и символическое поведение людей активного возраста.
Надо ли закавычивать НАРОДНУЮ КУЛЬТУРУ в этих предложениях ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Народная культура — традиционная культура, включающая культурные
>   пласты разных эпох от глубокой древности до настоящего времени,
>   субъектом которой является народ — коллективная личность, которая
>   означает объединение всех индивидов коллектива общностью культурных
>   связей и механизмов жизнедеятельности. Это культура бесписьменная,
>   именно поэтому в ней большое значение принадлежит традиции как способу
>   трансляции жизненно важной для общества информации.

Если фразы из вопроса не содержат иного отношения к предмету «Народная культура», этот термин закавычивать не следует.

P.S. Если что и брать в кавычки, то «модернизацию в народной культуре».

Comment: Мне кажется, что правильно так: ...и "модернизация" в народной культуре...

Comment: Словосочетание такое, что призадумаешься... А Доклад об итогах в «народной культуре»? Картина маслом. Кавычек не напасёшься.